# Copy files from a remote server which requires superuser preliveges to local machine

Tags: scp, winscp, pscp

Using `pscp` and when tried to copy files which needs root previleges.
 I am getting `Access denied error`.

```
pscp admin@<ip address>:<source> <destination>
```

I had to change the access previlege for the copying to work.

Is there a way to copy the files with elevated previleges?